How to limit a deserializing method to certain class instance
I have a static class for deserialization which should be only accessible to some of the class because only these class instance can be deserialized from the xml files and casted into that class type.
public static class Deserializer()
{
    public static T deserialize<T>(string path)    // T should be the classes that can do deserialization
    {
        // do deserialization
        return (T)(deserializedObject)
    }   
}

public class CanDoDeserialization()
{
    // class properties and methods
}        

public class CannotDoDeserialization()
{
    // class properties and methods
}

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        CanDoDeserialization canInstance = new CanDoDeserialization()
        canInstance = Deserializer.deserialize(somePath)      //this should be okay

        CannotDoDeserialization cannotInstance = new CannotDoDeserialization()
        cannotInstance = Deserializer.deserialize(somePath)    // this should raise compilation error
    }
}


But I do not know how to implement this. Using generic deserializing method as above raises the error of "The type arguments for method 'deserialize' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly." I have read about interface but it seems that it can only limit those classes which implement the interface but not others that do not? And letting the CanDoDeserialization class inherit from Deserializer also sounds not right, let alone inheritance from static class is prohibited.
Very much appreciated if anyone can give some hints on this. Thank you.

Supplmentary information:
The code above is a simplied version.  I want a general solution if let's say I have 10 classes that can do deserialization and 10 that cannot. What is the best approach to generalize this deserialization method that can be implemented by these 10 classes (or even more)?

The error is because the compiler cannot deduce T, so you need to write Deserializer.deserialize<CanDoDeserialization>(somePath) .

Why do you define a generic method if it can only work on a limited number of classes? You should define a set of overload methods, each corresponding to a class.

The code above is a simplifed version. I want a general solution if let's say I have ten classes that can do deserialization and ten that cannot. Then overloading the method in ten versions seems bad code.

The classes that can be serialized should have a common interface like ISerializable

@SomeBody Yes I think this is what I have been searching for. But I do not understand how do I prohibit those classes that do not have ISerializable to access the deserialize method? Where should I put the deserialize method?

The classes that can be serialized should have a common interface (e.g. ISerializable):
public interface ISerializable { }

public class CanDoDeserialization : ISerializable 
{
    // class properties and methods
}        

public class CannotDoDeserialization
{
    // class properties and methods
}

You should add this interface as a constraint to your generic Type T:
public static class Deserializer
{
    public static T deserialize<T>(string path)  where T : ISerializable 
    {
        // do deserialization
        return (T)(deserializedObject)
    }   
}

This will compile:
Deserializer.deserialize<CanDoDeserialization>("path");

This won't compile:
Deserializer.deserialize<CannotDoDeserialization>("path");

Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7jAHJN

Mind the possible clash with System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable

Thank you! That's what I am looking for. Have a hard time understanding how interface works.

You must create an abstract class that will serve as the base class for deserialization. Any class that extends it will be eligible for deserialization.
Exemple:
public abstract class SerializationBase
{
    // class properties and methods
}

public class CanDoDeserialization : SerializationBase
{
    // class properties and methods
}

public class CannotDoDeserialization
{
    // class properties and methods
}

public static class Deserializer
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string path) where T : SerializationBase  // Applying constraint to ensure T inherits from SerializationBase
    {
        // do deserialization
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string somePath = "path";  // Assuming this path is provided

        CanDoDeserialization canInstance = new CanDoDeserialization();
        canInstance = Deserializer.Deserialize<CanDoDeserialization>(somePath);  // this should be okay

        CannotDoDeserialization cannotInstance = new CannotDoDeserialization();
        cannotInstance = Deserializer.Deserialize<CannotDoDeserialization>(somePath);  // This will now raise a compile-time error
    }
}

